# Styles on buttons with children

Tags: button, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, children, win-universal-app

I have a question about styles. In my Windows Universal application I have certain buttons. These buttons have a stackpanel as a child and the stackpanel has an image as a child. The purpose of this is that the button needs to contain an image.

Now my employer wants to ignore the theme settings of the user. So whenever a button is clicked he doesn't want the background color of the button to change. The only way I've found so far to do this is with a style. However when I use a style the button is displayed without it's children. The style I made looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Button_style" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pointerleave">
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This was a proof of concept. However since the children of the buttons dissapear I'm unable to go on. How would I rewrite this style to make the children of the button stay where they are supposed to be?

Here is some sample code of the button I have:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" Click="MyButton_Click" ClickMode="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >  
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
         <Image Name="MyImage" x:Uid="MyImage" Source="" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="30" />
     </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore user settings at all the best option will be just override PhoneAccentBrush value. You can do it in App.xaml, or use ResourceDistionary.

```
  <Color x:Key="PhoneAccentColor">Blue</Color>
```

Also it is possible to request light or dark theme for your application in App.xaml:

```
  <Application x:Class="App1.App"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:local="using:App2"
               RequestedTheme="Light">
  </Application>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I'll try this. But this probably only works for the phone part of the project. Is there something similar for windows modern applications?

Comment: You are right. This will work only for phone. In store apps you can override ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush resource. But this differs for other controls. The full list of ThemeResouces is availiable here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn518235.aspx